# Wrapper for javascript map function

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, parameter-passing, eval, wrapper

I have two javascript functions stack(y, f) and val(yi, x).

stack(y, f) should behave like
`y.map(function(yi) { f } )`

it returns an array r, where each element r[i] is a function of the corresponding element of an array parameter y[i] and an expression f passed as second parameter.

f can be any javascript code that evaluates to a single value, however, if it depends on function val, this function would depend on y[i].

`[r[0], r[1], ...] = stack( [y[0], y[1], ...], foo( val(y[i], x1), val(y[i], x2), ... ) )`

I considered the following ugly approach, where I pass the expression as string, and in a loop string-replace - then evaluate it.
https://jsfiddle.net/zuyt954g/

```
function val(yi,x) {
    return 10**yi+x;
}

function foo(x1,x2,x3) {
    return x1+x2+x3;
}

function stack(y,f) {
    return y.map(function(yi) {
        return eval(f.replace(/yi/g, yi));
    });
}

console.log([1,2].map(function(yi) {
  return foo(val(yi,3),val(yi,4),val(yi,5))
} ))
>> [42, 312]

console.log(stack([1,2], "foo(val(yi,3),val(yi,4),val(yi,5))"))
>> [42, 312]
```

I wonder whether you could see any cleaner solution, where ideally I would avoid evaluating a string expression. As an alternative I thought of already val returning an array, if it detects stack as one of its distant parents, but getting the call stack and y seems non-trivial.

Comment: I don't understand why not pass a function instead? `"foo(val(yi,3),val(yi,4),val(yi,5))"` -> `function(yi) { return foo(val(yi,3),val(yi,4),val(yi,5)) }`

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> any cleaner solution, where ideally I would avoid evaluating a string expression

Simple, just use a function instead. You get rid of the very error prone strings, you make your code more maintainable, and you make it easier to read and understand.

The string `"foo(val(yi,3),val(yi,4),val(yi,5))"` can be transformed into the function:

```js
function(yi) {
    return foo(val(yi,3),val(yi,4),val(yi,5));
}
```

and when called instead of replacing the string `yi`, now you can just pass it in, so

```js
eval(f.replace(/yi/g, yi));
```

transforms into simply

```js
f(yi);
```

Here is how this transformation looks:

```js
function val(yi, x) {
  return 10 ** yi + x;
}

function foo(x1, x2, x3) {
  return x1 + x2 + x3;
}

function stack(y, f) {
  return y.map(function(yi) {
    return f(yi);
  })
}

console.log([1, 2].map(function(yi) {
  return foo(val(yi, 3), val(yi, 4), val(yi, 5))
}))
//>> [42, 312]

console.log(stack([1, 2], function(yi) {
  return foo(val(yi, 3), val(yi, 4), val(yi, 5))
}))
//>> [42, 312]
```

However, now we can improve it a bit. There is a bit of redundancy here:

```js
return y.map(function(yi) {
  return f(yi);
})
```

`map` receives a callback, that takes one parameter and calls another function that also takes the same parameter. Both functions have [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) of 1 the only purpose of the anonymous callback is to forward the parameter to `f`. Therefore, calling the anonymous callback with `yi` is the same as calling `f(yi)`. We can remove this "empty wrapper" by what in Lambda Calculus is called [Eta reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-reduction) since `f` does *exactly* the same as the callback. In our case this means that `stack` becomes:

```js
function stack(y, f) {
  return y.map(f)
}
```

As a final note, we can further prove the equality by just re-using the function

```js
function(yi) {
  return foo(val(yi, 3), val(yi, 4), val(yi, 5))
}
```

which now exists twice:

```js
function val(yi, x) {
  return 10 ** yi + x;
}

function foo(x1, x2, x3) {
  return x1 + x2 + x3;
}

function stack(y, f) {
  return y.map(f);
}

function testFunction(yi) {                        // ---|
  return foo(val(yi, 3), val(yi, 4), val(yi, 5));  //    |->-
}                                                  // ---|  |
//                                                          v
//                                                          |
console.log([1, 2].map(testFunction)) //<-----------------<--
//>> [42, 312]                                              |
//                                                          v
//                                                          |
console.log(stack([1, 2], testFunction)) //<--------------<--
//>> [42, 312]
```